# Breadth First Search with Python List

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I'm trying to code an algorithm to find the best path from one node `s` to another one `f` by Breadth First Search. I found the following code and I almost understand it all, but I don't get what are they doing in this line:

```
while frontier: ...
```

My questions are

- What frontier means on the graph?
- For how much time will while condition be true, or what depends on?

Here's the code:

```
Graph_Adjs={'s':['a','x'],'a':['s','z'],'x':['s','d','c'],'z':['a'],'d':['x','c','f'], 'c':['d','x','f','v'],'f':['d','c','v'],'v':['f','c'] }

def BFS (Graph_Adjs,s='s'):
    level = {'s':0}
    father = {'s':None}
    i = 1
    frontier = [s]

    while frontier:
        next = []
        for u in frontier:
            for v in Graph_Adjs[u]:
               if v not in level:
                    level[v] = i
                    father[v] = u
                    next.append(v)
        frontier = next
        i+=1
return father

if __name__=='__main__':
    father = BFS (Graph_Adjs,s='s')
    f = 'f'
    path = []
    while f !=None:
        path.append(f)
        f = father[f]
    path.reverse()
    print (path)
```

Comment: which of the `next = []`; `next.append(v)`; `frontier = next` didn't you understand?

Comment: My doubt it was about frontier itself, what it represents on the graph? Neighbour nodes of the current node visited?

Comment: frontier are all the nodes that are to be handled next - they're the current... well, exterior part of the breadth-first search...

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the truth value of a list is True if it's non empty and False otherwise. The condition is effectively implementing a way to record visited nodes, so they are not iterated over again.